# How to deal with content that will be added later in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, canvas

I want to control a canvas that is automatically created in the run-time.
The problem here is that `jQuery` function will have to deal with a content that isn't exist when the page is `ready`.

```
$(document).ready(function(ee) {
     $("#containerInsertBtn").click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $("#container").html("<canvas width='300' height='300' id='tk'>fall</canvas>");    
    });

    $("#tk").click(function(eg) {
        alert('tic');
    });

});
```

The HTML Markup:

```
<div id="container" contenteditable="true"></div>
<button id="containerInsertBtn">Add Canvas</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use .on() for that, like:

```
$(document).on("click", "#tk", function(eg) {
   alert('tic');
});
```

OR,

```
$(document).on("click", "canvas", function() {
   console.log( $(this).attr("id") ); //gives you the id of clicked canvas
});
```

See more here:: [jQuery .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: but if I have many canvases and I want to assign the tag-name "canvas" instead of "#tk" to avoid writing the same code many times. so how can I refer to the clicked canvas?

Comment: @DevelopSmith you could use $(this) to refer to specific canvas you are working on, as in added code in my answer above..

Answer (score 0):

You can (as other answers have suggested) use `on`, or for your simple case, you can just bind your event at the same time the element comes into existence.

You don't have to bind all your events at the top-level inside your `ready` callback:

```
$(document).ready(function(ee) {
    $("#containerInsertBtn").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#container").html("<canvas width='300' height='300' id='tk'>fall</canvas>");    

        $("#tk").click(function(eg) {
            alert('tic');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: yes it is very useful. I will try both the two solutions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because a dynamically created element will not be included on DOM while the event handler is executed.

Your solution is event delegation. jQuery has [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to do that.

```
$("body").on('click', '#tk', function(e) {
    //....
});
```

You need to specify a parent container to delegate the events to its child elements liek `#tk`

If you want to delegate to a element based on its tag name, its as same as the above.

```
$("body").on('click', 'canvas', function(e) {
    console.log($(this)); // you can access the active element by using $(this)
    //....
});
```

Comment: well I gotcha. But if I have many canvases and I want to assign the tag-name "canvas" instead of "#tk" to avoid writing the same code many times. so how can I refer to the clicked canvas?